# A paper is published in a book, conference and its proceedings, should I cite it as book, conference or conference proceeding paper?

Tags: citations, conference, citation-style, reference-managers, proceedings

I use Mendeley reference manager and sometimes import articles from browser to my Mendeley Library using browser extension. Import is totally fine but I am having two confusions after importing:

1. Some conference papers are published in **Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science (LNCS)** and many other related Lecture Notes series of Springer. When I add it to Mendeley, it categorizes that paper as **"Book"** although it was originally published in a conference. So should I cite this paper as

   - an article in a book titled **LNCS** or
   - **Conference in which it was published** or
   - **Conference proceedings in which it was published**?

Please refer to following image as an example of this. First screenshot is from Springer site and second is from Mendeley Desktop paper details section.

[image: Springer cite paper screenshot]
[image: Mendeley screenshot of above imported paper]

2. If I have to cite it as a Conference proceeding, then what should be name of the Conference Proceeding,

   - the name written as **"Proceedings of International Conference on XYZ"** or
   - the actual title of proceeding as "**XYZ"**?

Taking the above picture as an example: Here, the title of conference is **"International Conference on Human Centered Computing"** and Proceeding name is **"Human Center Computing"**. Should I refer title as "Proceedings of International Conference on Human Centered Computing" or just "Human Centered Computing"?

3. If that paper is Workshop paper of that conference, in this case, what would be citation style, workshop title, Conference title or proceedings title?

Please help me understand this. Thanks in anticipation.

PS Pardon me if all three of the above should be posted as separate questions but I think these all all related to one another like an IF/ELSE condition and may help in reaching a conclusion.

Comment: In the specific case of Springer, you can find the recommended way to cite near the bottom of the page of each paper on Springer's website. In your image, see the "Cite as" link.

Comment: In addition to what @GoodDeeds said, you could simply google the titles of some of the other papers published in the same conference proceedings and see how they are cited in publications, looking to see if there is a reasonably consistent way they are cited.

Answer (score 1):

People in the field will recognize the article for what it is, so there is no real danger of confusion. Depending on the discipline, there is a hierarchy, where, for example, book chapters are considered to be less prestigious than a conference. In this case, you would use the citation style appropriate for the highest element in the hierarchy. In your case, this would be the HCC17 conference, e.g. Proceedings of International Conference on Human Centered Computing, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 10757, Springer, 2018. Here, Proceedings and LCNS vol 10757 are at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a journal article, follow the journal's instructions.  If there are no instructions, imitate papers they have recently published.

If you are doing homework or writing a thesis, ask your professor.  Do not be surprised if they do not care.

So long as the paper is easy to find from the citation, any of these approaches is reasonable.